# How do I prevent regular requirement changes which invalidates my work?

Tags: unprofessional-behavior

In a team there is a manager and also a "coordinator" to oversee the project (he is not my line manager).

Once I have been assigned a task, I check with both the manager and coordinator what exactly is this entails - sometimes I do this more than once because of previous problems.

On numerous occasions the coordinator has changed the project after I have spent a significant amount of time on the work. I have confronted him about this but he won't acknowledge any wrong doing. I have complained to the manager who has stated I am not flexible enough. This last time I worked on a project for 2 weeks and then he emailed the whole team to say he had amended this work and tried to say it wasn't the work that was assigned. So untrue - he had once again changed the goalposts mid way through but without telling me. I thought this very unprofessional and told him so. The manager said that the coordinator didn't mean to be offensive or unprofessional but I replied that the coordinator should be telling me this not you. He refused to acknowledge any wrong doing. The manager told me I was reading it wrong and not to get so upset. The coordinator was at no time addressed about his behaviour and actions.

How can I prevent my coworker from regularly making requirement changes which invalidates work I've already done?

Comment: It sounds like you're more angry that he doesn't want to apologise to you, which I wouldn't really expect to have happen anyway - he doesn't report to you, and that he's not experiencing any consequences, which you simply can't know - just because it's not public doesn't mean it's not happening, or maybe what he's doing is just his job (does he have to report to clients, investors or upper management?).

Comment: I edited your question and removed "What is my next step?", since that doesn't give your question [a goal we can address](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2696), and I tried to replace that with a more appropriate question - if the question I added is not what you want to know, feel free to [edit] your post and change it.

Comment: If you cannot handle frequent changes in the requirements perhaps you are not temperamentally suited to software development.

Comment: Not particularly helpful, but I cannot resist: welcome to the real world!

Answer (score 6):

It is true that the people who are paying for the software to be developed can change what they want to have developed at any time. However, it is not true that they can do so without consequences.

So next time you're asked for (for example) a screen that shows these 4 columns, in this order, and then when it's almost done they say actually two of those columns we don't need, but we need these 3 extra ones, and there needs to be totals, plus the user should be able to sort by any column just by clicking on the heading, and also we should remember what sort order they used last time, you don't say:

> You can't do that! I already started! This isn't fair!

Instead you say:

> Ok, I can do that. If you had given me these requirements a week ago when you gave me the previous spec for this screen, I would have given you a longer estimate because it's more work. Plus, I've already started this screen. I think I can reuse some of what I've already done. Give me an hour to work out how much extra effort this will be. Then we can either change the deploy date or move some other task to the next iteration to make sure this gets done.

(If you don't mind paid overtime, that's another way to make sure everything gets done, but I don't like to offer that as a first response to changes.)

This response is friendly and helpful. It says "I can do what you want". It reminds the person that this isn't what they wanted before, and that there are consequences to their request. (There's a huge difference between "I think I can reuse some of what I have already done" and "I am going to have to throw away a large part of what I have already done!" for example, even though they have the same literal meaning.) If the project manager tries saying that the release date won't slip and the contents just have to be this new larger amount of work, that is something you need to discuss with your manager. The basic concept of "we don't want what we asked for and we want something else" is not negotiable though, and you trying to prevent that will be at best frustrating and at worst a career limiting move.

Answer (score 5):

> How can I prevent my coworker from regularly making requirement
>   changes which invalidates work I've already done?

You cannot.

The nature of many projects these days is that requirements are never frozen. Those writing and managing the requirements feel free to change them as they see fit. The days of waterfall projects are over in many companies (at least for now). The coordinator and manager have signaled to you on numerous occasions that requirements can be changed when the coordinator decides it is appropriate. It's time to accept that decision and get on board.

You can minimize the rework by trying to understand which portions of the requirements are more likely to be changed and which parts are less likely. Then you work on the parts that feel more "safe". Meeting and working closely with the coordinator and your manager every week or so can help you identify what portions to prioritize and what to de-prioritize. Make sure you save notes from each meeting so that if questions ever arise, you can refer to them. You might consider sharing these notes with the team (including the coordinator and manager).

Make sure that whenever requirements are changed, you update your estimates to take the new reality into account. You can't stop requirements changes, but you must explain the business costs associated with them.

Some companies have gone to an Agile project management style that formalizes the approach. But (as seems the case in your company), some just run projects as they choose without a formal approach.

You could leave this company and try to ask about requirements during interviews before you pick your next company.

Otherwise, you'll just need to learn to deal with requirements that are pretty much ever-changing.